# make variable from variable javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables, addition

i am trying to add data to an array where part of the array name is a variable.

if that makes sense?

this is my coding, i think its something to do with the ["charts"[d]] part but nothing is being added to the arrays

```
    var 
    charts0 = [],
    charts1 = [],
    charts2 = [],
    charts3 = []
    var newdata = data.split("|");
    var newdates = dates.split(",");
    for (i = 0; i < newdates.length; i++) { 
        for (d = 0; d < newdata.length; d++) { 
        var dataparts = newdata[d].split(",");
        ["charts"[d]].push({x: newdates[i], y: dataparts[i+1]});

        }
    }
```

Comment: It cannot be done (exept for using eval, which you shouldn't).

Comment: If you want to name something, just add one extra layer of array on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object literal as an associative array.

```
var charts = {
  charts0: [],
  charts1: []
};


/* ... */

charts['charts' + d].push( // ...
```

But if you are going to do this, you could simply use an array, where the indices are implicit:

```
var charts = [[],[]];

/* ... */

charts[d].push( // ...
```

Comment: What's the point in using ES6 computed property names for this? Just use the number without brackets, or maybe an array initialiser.

Comment: Number without the brackets is invalid syntax?

Comment: See [Object Initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5). A *PropertyName* can be a *NumericLiteral*.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new object with your arrays like

```
var ch = {
    charts0: [],
    charts1: [],
    charts2: [],
    charts3: []
}
```

Then you'll be able to do ch["charts" + d][i] etc..

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it right now is not possible (without using eval, which you shouldn't). You can however add an extra 'layer' with your variables by using an object. Like so:

```
var myData = {
    charts0: [],
    charts1: []
    charts2: []
    charts3: []
};

var newdata = data.split("|");
var newdates = dates.split(",");

for (i = 0; i < newdates.length; i++) { 
    for (d = 0; d < newdata.length; d++) { 
           var dataparts = newdata[d].split(",");
           myData['charts' + d].push({x: newdates[i], y: dataparts[i+1]});
    }
}
```